# Calculate weighted mean with different types of rows

Tags: excel

I want to track the **weighted mean price per coin** of my crypto currencies in excel.
But I don't know what would be the best approach for my table which looks like this:

```
| Type | Total Price | Price Per Coin | Coins     |
|------|-------------|----------------|-----------|
| Buy  | 250         | 7.80           | 32,051282 |
| Buy  | 300         | 7.42           | 40,431266 |
| Sell | 270         | 7.61           | 35,479632 |
```

To calculate the weighted mean one would use the formula:

```
SUMPRODUCT([Price Per Coin], [Coins])/SUM([Coins])
```

But in my case the table also holds `Sell` rows which that I don't want in the calculation of the weighted mean for the `Buy` price of my coins. How can I exclude them from the formula?

I tried something like:

```
SUMPRODUCT([Price Per Coin], [Coins])/SUMIF([Type], "==Buy", [Coins])
```

But this doesn't some to be right (I got a result way over 15 bucks per coin which doesn't make sense...).

How could I furthermore calculate how much I've made/lost with my transactions?

Comment: If i understood your question, in example 2 there is that you want: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e

Answer (score 1):

If you have O365:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(coinTbl,coinTbl[Type]="Buy"),SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(x,0,3),INDEX(x,0,4))/SUM(INDEX(x,0,4)))
```

`=> 7.588`

If you don't have O365, this should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(coinTbl[Price Per Coin]*(coinTbl[Type]="Buy"),coinTbl[Coins]*(coinTbl[Type]="Buy"))/SUMIF(coinTbl[Type],"Buy",coinTbl[Coins])
```

Your second question probably deserves to be separate and include a discussion of what you mean and how you want to calculate your profit/loss  Recognized, unrecognized, FIFO, average cost, or some other method.

And also why you are, apparently, using different decimal indicators in your price and coins columns.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table would let you filter away SELL rows and instantly calculate the sum of total_price, sum of coins

To get proper weighted average you can either refer to the pivot table totals or follow this guide (i just googled for excel weighted average pivot table)

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4816-excel-pivot-table-weighted-average.html

Although I am curious because using the data you provided it looks like  remaining balance of coins is only 37 not 72

Seems to me you need to at least add more columns to store Coin_balance  to track remaining unsold coins for each  Buy row